# Цикл for по полям структуры

Tags: golang, циклы, структуры, foreach, struct

У меня есть структура и я хочу в функции `pointSearch` пройти по всем переменным структуры. Выполняю `for _, val := range p`, но выдает ошибку. Если я напишу `result = p.x1 + p.x2 + p.x3` то все работает нормально.

Как же записать эту сумму в виде цикла?

```golang
type float64x3 struct {
  x1, x2, x3 float64
}

func (p float64x3) pointSearch ()float64 {
  var result float64 = 0;
  for _,val := range p {
    result = result + val
  }
  return result
}

func main() {
  param := float64x3{52.123123, 36.123123, 5};
  result := param.pointSearch();
  fmt.Println(result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type float64x3 struct {
    X1,X2,X3 float64
}

func (p float64x3) pointSearch ()float64 {
  var result float64 = 0;
  val := reflect.ValueOf(p);
  for i := 0; i< val.NumField(); i++ {
     result +=val.Field(i).Interface().(float64);
  }
  return result;
}

func main() {
    param := float64x3{52.123123, 36.123123, 5};
    result := param.pointSearch();
    fmt.Println(result);
}
```

Результат: `93.246246`

Answer (score -1):

Без применения отражения, которое в свою очередь приносит *боль*,
итерация по полям структуры невозможна. Если вы планируете очень часто
что-то подобное делать, вам будет куда легче воспользоваться массивом
(не путать со срезами!):

```golang
type float64x3 [3]float64

func (p *float64x3) pointSearch() (sum float64) {
    for _, v := range p {
        sum += v
    }

    return sum
}
```

*Playground*:
https://play.golang.org/p/dFo9oe4OjL4.

---

Альтернативное предложение — определить метод, возвращающий все поля
структуры в массиве или в срезе. Пример со срезом:

```golang
type float64x3 struct {
    x, y, z float64
}

func (p *float64x3) coords() (triple []float64) {
    return []float64{p.x, p.y, p.z}
}

func (p *float64x3) pointSearch() (sum float64) {
    for _, v := range p.coords() {
        sum += v
    }

    return sum
}
```

*Playground*:
https://play.golang.org/p/Bqd8VtaeF8m.

Comment: @And Вы го с каким-то другим языком перепутали. Во-первых, `...` нельзя применять к ресиверу. Во-вторых, `...` не работает с полями структуры.